# Splitting values and assigning keys

Tags: python

I have a json array with long and lat values combined, and fields are empty. I am trying to figure out a python script to loop through the array and separate them into long and lat keys.

```
[
  {
    "Shape": "(47.630880207000075, -122.37391463199998)"
  },
  {
    "Shape": ""
  },
  {
    "Shape": "(47.70118823100006, -122.38447021399998)"
  }
]
```

output desired:

```
[
  {
    "Long": "47.630880207000075",
    "Lat": "-122.37391463199998"

  },
  {
     "Long": "",
    "Lat": ""
  },
  {
   "Long": "47.70118823100006",
    "Lat": "-122.38447021399998"
  }
]
```

---

So far I have converted the CSV into JSON and in the process of figuring out the regex to loop through it.. code so far:

import csv

```
import json

csvfile = open('geoloc.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

# fieldnames = ("S")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile)
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ], sort_keys=True, indent=4 )
jsonfile.write(out)
```

Comment: The values are *strings*?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes doesn't matter could be reconverted to int easily anyway

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easy to use `ast.literal_eval` to turn this into a `tuple` vs. `re`, e.g.:

```
In [1]:
import ast
def tuple_convert(t):
    return ast.literal_eval(t) if t else ('', '')

keys = ['Long', 'Lat']
[dict(zip(keys, tuple_convert(d['Shape']))) for d in data]

Out[1]:
[{'Lat': -122.37391463199998, 'Long': 47.630880207000075},
 {'Lat': '', 'Long': ''},
 {'Lat': -122.38447021399998, 'Long': 47.70118823100006}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `json` is loaded to `d`

```
>>> l = [{"Long": c['Shape'][1:-1].split(',')[0].strip() if len(c['Shape']) > 0 else '',
"Lat": c['Shape'][1:-1].split(',')[1].strip() if len(c['Shape']) > 0 else ''} for c in d]
>>> l
[{'Lat': '-122.37391463199998', 'Long': '47.630880207000075'},
 {'Lat': '', 'Long': ''},
 {'Lat': '-122.38447021399998', 'Long': '47.70118823100006'}]
```

EDIT:
To make it more readable:

```
l = [ dict(zip(['Long', 'Lat'],c['Shape'][1:-1].split(',') if len(c['Shape'])>0 else ['',''] ))  for c in d]
```

Comment: Why, oh why, would you try to fit that into a single comprehension?

Comment: It is totally unreadable. *Readability counts*, and is much more important than the marginal speedup you will see making a for-loop into a list-comprehension.